# How can solve this trouble, only need turn the arrow vertically

Tags: tikz-arrows, math-operators, pgfmath, charts, floating

```
\documentclass[10pt,headinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%The package allows the user to select font encodings, and for each encoding provides an interface to ‘font-encoding-specific’ commands for each font.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}%these pakcage define of color each one spine of fish
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{155, 87, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mrot}{RGB}{255, 70, 70}
    \definecolor{mgrun}{RGB}{41, 175, 0}
    \definecolor{mlila}{RGB}{136, 55, 155}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->, remember picture]
    `>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>---------------Here ------------------------------->>>>>>>`
    \node (bq) [anchor=south, yshift=13pt+\abovecaptionskip, rectangle, draw, fill=mgrau1] at (current page text area.south) {\small Posicionamiento de objetos por antena};
`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--------------and There---------------------------->>>>>>>>`
            \node[anchor=west] (met) at ($(current page text area.north west)-(0,5)$) {\small\color{mturkis}Metodo};
                \node (bau) at ($(met)+(5,3)$) {\color{mturkis}Bauteil};
                \node (bel) at ($(met)+(3,4)$) {\color{mturkis}Belichtung};
            \node[anchor=west] (mes) at (current page text area.west)                   {\small\color{mrot}Medicion};
            \node[anchor=west] (men) at ($(current page text area.south west)+(0,5)$) {\small\color{mlila}Mano de Obra};

            \node[anchor=east] (mas) at ($(current page text area.north east)-(0,5)$) {\small\color{mgelb}Maquina};
            \node[anchor=east] (mit) at (current page text area.east)                   {\small\color{mblau}Medioambiente};
            \node[anchor=east] (mat) at ($(current page text area.south east)+(0,5)$) {\small\color{mgrun}Material};

        \draw[ultra thick] (current page text area.north) -- (bq);
            \draw[very thick, mturkis] (met.east) -- ($(met-|bq)-(0.8pt,0)$);
                \draw[thick, mturkis] (bau.south) -- ($(met-|bq)-(0.8pt,0)$);
            \draw[very thick, mrot] (mes.east) -- ($(mes-|bq)-(0.8pt,0)$);
            \draw[very thick, mlila] (men.east) -- ($(men-|bq)-(0.8pt,0)$);

            \draw[very thick, mgelb] (mas.west) -- ($(mas-|bq)+(0.8pt,0)$);
            \draw[very thick, mblau] (mit.west) -- ($(mit-|bq)+(0.8pt,0)$);
            \draw[very thick, mgrun] (mat.west) -- ($(mat-|bq)+(0.8pt,0)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test caption for vertical spacing}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Have the frist code then need change the orientation of the middle arrow, but I try moved the code spans whit the next  command

```
`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>---------------Here ------------------------------->>>>>>>`
              \node (bq) [anchor=north, yshift=13pt+\abovecaptionskip, rectangle, draw, fill=mgrau1] at (current page text area.north) {\small Posicionamiento de objetos por antena};
`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--------------and There---------------------------->>>>>>>>`
```

but only achive move to up middle and not only in middle, the arrow aslo i can achive twist the nort direccion but whith one displacement to up as mention back.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you just replace `\draw[ultra thick] (current page text area.north) -- (bq);` with `\draw[ultra thick] ([yshift=13pt+\abovecaptionskip]current page text area.south) -- (bq);`?

Comment: @SandyG I can, but these change don't resolve my needs, in all only in direction but in place, these solution move de arrow turned to left and me need in middle not in left. hope have clear in this time.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want. Perhaps a picture would help, even if you draw it by hand.

Comment: ok don worry it was it.